# Why classes extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and not declaring any bean are annotated with configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

According to [@Configuration documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html):

> Indicates that a **class declares one or more @Bean methods** and may be processed by the Spring container to generate bean definitions and service requests for those beans at runtime, for example:

```
@Configuration  
public class AppConfig {  
  @Bean  
  public MyBean myBean() {  
    //instantiate, configure and return bean ...  
  }  
}
```

As I remember always I came across classes extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` which didn't contain any `@Bean` methods and were annotated with `@Configuration`.
It is even in official blog and some examples, see:
https://spring.io/blog/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class HelloWebSecurityConfiguration
   extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    auth
      .inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
  }
}
```

or here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html

```
    @Order(1)                                                        2
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/api/**")                               3
                .authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                    authorizeRequests
                        .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
                )
                .httpBasic(withDefaults());
        }
    }
```

Why this classes are annotated with `@Configuration` even though there are no `@Bean` methods?

Comment: It isn't a requirement for an `@Configuration` to have bean methods. The `@Configuration` is more or less an identifier for classes that define the configuration of your application. The `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is such a thing it is part of the application configuration. Also `@Configuration` classes are processed slightly differently then other `@Component` annotations. Finally the `@EnableWebSecurity` will import several other `@Configuration` class which do supply beans.

Comment: @M.Deinum I found one quote:  
> Configuration is a stereotype that declares the class as a configuration class, that is a class that is creating bean instances to be added to the context (via Bean methods) and/or other top-level declarations that affect the context (such as ComponentScan or EnableXyz).  

which I like more than:   
>It isn't a requirement for an Configuration to have bean methods. The Configuration is more or less an identifier for classes that define the configuration of your application.  

Cause I can imagine that someone could have wrong definition of configuration.

Comment: quote source: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12901

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beans are [imported using the secondary "@Enable" annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html)

> Spring features such as asynchronous method execution, scheduled task execution, annotation driven transaction management, and even Spring MVC can be enabled and **configured from @Configuration classes using their respective "@Enable" annotations**. See @EnableAsync, @EnableScheduling, @EnableTransactionManagement, @EnableAspectJAutoProxy, and @EnableWebMvc for details.

from [EnableWebSecurity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/EnableWebSecurity.html):

> Add this annotation to an @Configuration class to have the Spring Security configuration defined in any WebSecurityConfigurer or more likely by extending the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter base class and overriding individual methods: